# Как обратится к элементу если их несколько одинаковых на странице?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть несколько элементов с одинаковым классом. Как можно обратится ко второму из них?

```html
<div id="myid" class="myclass">
    <span class="btn">
        <i class="icn"></i>
        <i class="icn"></i> // Нужно обратится к этому элементу
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll('.icn')[1]` к примеру

Comment: SwaD, а есть ещё какие-нибудь способы?

Comment: Их много. [Выбирайте](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass .icn');
if (elements.length > 1) {
  const secondElement = elements[1]; // Второй элемент

}
```